# How to release anonymous event hander resource?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Suppose I have a ViewModel with Event Loaded. I want to release the the handler immediately after hook it up. It means only hookup one time. I want to use anonymous in following way:

```
EventHandler handler = (s, e) =>
{
   //......             
   vm.Loaded -= handler;;
};

vm.Loaded += handler;
```

it is not working. I don't want to use named handler separately. What's the solution for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you declare the EventHandler first:

```
EventHandler handler = null;
handler = (s, e) => 
{    
    //......                 
    vm.Loaded -= handler;
};
```